Quantum electron transport through perfect interface
I would like to study the conductance of electrons through two semi-infinite leads which meet at a perfect interface. The leads are composed of a layered material which is periodic in the transverse directions, so the transverse component of the momentum $\vec{k}_\parallel$ is a good quantum number. The layers and the interlayer coupling are described by a tight-binding model. The transmission function is given by the Caroli formula
$$
T(E;\vec{k}_\parallel)
=\mbox{Tr}\left\{G(E;\vec{k}_\parallel)\,\Gamma(E;\vec{k}_\parallel)G^{\dagger}(E;\vec{k}_\parallel)\,\Gamma(E;\vec{k}_\parallel)\right\}
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the level-shift matrix (assumed to be the same for both leads), $G$ is the Green's function of the interfacial region, $T(E;\vec{k}_\parallel)$ is the transmission function, and $\mbox{Tr}$ denotes the trace.
For a truly 1D system, the above formula would not depend on $\vec{k}_\parallel$. For the case in question, however, I'm guessing the "true" transmission function of the system is obtained by averaging over all $\vec{k}_\parallel$; i.e.
$$
T(E)\overset{?}{=}
\int\frac{d^2\vec{k}_\parallel}{4\pi^2}\,T(E;\vec{k}_\parallel)
$$
but I don't know what I should take as the domain of integration. Would it just be the (2D) Brillouin zone of a given layer in the lead?
